# How is the synchronization of multiple engines managed in twin engined aircraft?

Tags: engine

If one of the two engines of an aircraft is running at slightly less RPM then the other, how the synchronization is being managed?

Also, if there are more than 2 engines in the aircraft, how that will effect?